# Node.js Bluebird Promise: promise.any to return default image

Tags: node.js, bluebird

Using Bluebird promises in a node.js environment, I check if any or none of three possible variations of a file exists (image.png/image.gif/image.jpg) on my server. If one of those three files exists, it shall be returned to the user. If none of the three files exist, a default image shall be returned. So far, I came up with this code:

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.statAsync('./image.jpg')
    .then(function(result) {
        if(result){
            resolve('jpg');
        }
    }).catch(function(err){
        //foo
    });    
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.statAsync('./image.gif')
    .then(function(result) {
        if(result){
            resolve('gif');
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        //foo
    });    
});

var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.statAsync('./image.png')
    .then(function(result) {
        if(result){
            resolve('png');
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        //foo
    });    
});

Promise.any([
    promise1,
    promise2,
    promise3
]).then(function(result) {
    res.sendfile("./image."+result);
}).catch(function(err){
    res.sendfile("./default.png");
});
```

Problem is: as long as one of those three files exists, everything works just fine. But I can't get it to work to have the default image to be returned in case none of the three files can be found.

Comment: You need to use `reject` in each promise if image not found

Comment: This is an anti-pattern to create these new promises when you can just use the ones that `fs.statAsync()` already returns.  You can evaluate the result in the `.then()` handler and change the resolved status if desired.  No need to wrap these in their own new promises.  In fact, several of your bugs are because of this promise wrapping which is both unnecessary and prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

`statAsync` already returns a `Promise`, so you don't need to create your own (doing so is [an antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern)). If you simply map the resolved `Stats` value to the value you want, you won't need to worry about `resolve` and `reject` calls, etc.

```
var promise1 = fs.statAsync('./image.jpg')
    .then(function () { return 'jpg'; });

var promise2 = fs.statAsync('./image.gif')
    .then(function () { return 'gif'; });

var promise3 = fs.statAsync('./image.png')
    .then(function () { return 'png'); });

Promise.any([
    promise1,
    promise2,
    promise3
]).then(function(result) {
    res.sendfile("./image."+result);
}).catch(function(err){
    res.sendfile("./default.png");
});
```

As mentioned in a comment posted against your question, your code is not working because, when `statAsync` fails, you are not rejecting the `Promise` you created, but you should not need to create your own `Promise` in the first place.

Comment: Sorry about the antipattern. I should know better. It's just that at times I'm still struggling with the concept of promises and passing of resolved/rejected events. In fact, why is the code above working? I mean, there is no reject or throw instruction. Why does catch come into play?! :-/

Comment: An SO answer - much less a comment - isn't really the best place to explain how/why promises work. However, the above code works because the `statAsync` implementation resolves or rejects the promise and the `Promise.any` implementation wires up the `then` and `catch` calls. If all promises in the array are rejected, the `catch` chained to the `Promise.any` will be called. If a single promise in the array resolves, the `then` chained to the `Promise.any` will be called. You should have no problem finding introductory/explanatory information elsewhere.